# BC31143 Error when using a delegate in a form load

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a form with two types of datas:

- current datas which have to be displayed when the form is shown
- historical datas which may be displayed if the user click on a dedicated button.
  Both types came from a database.

As historical datas might take more time to get, i'd like to get them after the form is shown.

The form is opened through this:

```
Public Sub DisplayUgc(_strIdUgcToDisplay As String, _strPlatformUgcToDisplay As String)
   Dim frmUgcNotice as New frmNoticeUgc
   If IsMyFormOpened(frmUgcNotice) = False Then
      frmUgcNotice.strIdUgcToDisplay = _strIdUgcToDisplay
      frmUgcNotice.strPlatformUgcToDisplay = _strPlatformUgcToDisplay
      frmUgcNotice.Show()
   Else
      MsgBox(strMsgNoticeAlreadyOpened, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, strMsgBoxGeneralErrorTitle)
      Exit Sub
   End If

'[...Then, some code where every other controls in the form is set...]
```

So, to get what i'd like and following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317974/11894831), i did this:

```
Public Class frmNoticeUgc
    Inherits Form

    Public Delegate Sub DoWorkDelegate()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub    
    Friend tblHistoricalDatas As New DataTable  ' Historical Datas
    Friend WithEvents strIdUgcToDisplay As String
    Friend WithEvents strPlatformUgcToDisplay As String
    Private Sub frmNoticeUgc_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        
        InitUgcCombobox()
        InitUgcDatagrid()

        Select Case Me.btnValidation.Text
            Case "Ajouter"
                SetFormControls("add")
            Case "Modifier"
                Me.tblHistoricalDatas  = BeginInvoke(New DoWorkDelegate(AddressOf GetHistoricalDatas(Me.strIdUgcToDisplay, Me.strPlatforme))
                SetFormControls("modify")
        End Select
        SetFormColor(Me)

    End Sub
```

With `GetHistoricalDatas` like:

```
Public Function GetHistoricalDatas(_strUserId As String, _strPlatforme As String) As DataTable
      Dim tblGetAllVersions As Datatable
      ' [...] Some code to get the historical datas

       Return tblGetAllVersions
        
End Function
```

Issue: i have a BC31143, Method 'Public Function GetHistoricalDatas(_strUserId As String, _strPlatforme As String) As DataTable' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'frmNoticeUgc.DoWorkDelegate'.
I don't understand what causes this issue condiering that tblHistoricalDatas is a datatable and GetHistoricalDatas returns a datatable

What did i miss?

Precision: `GetHistoricalDatas` is not in the form code, this function is located elsewhere in the project. But, as it's a public function, i'm assuming (maybe i'm wrong), it won't be an issue.

Comment: You think that the declaration of this:  `Public Delegate Sub DoWorkDelegate()` matches this: `Function GetHistoricalDatas(_strUserId As String, _strPlatforme As String) As DataTable`? What's this delegate for? Do you actually need it? Can't you just use a Lambda? -- Why are you calling `BeginInvoke()` there? -- What's the point of this: `Friend WithEvents strIdUgcToDisplay As String`?

Comment: I didn't "think anything", that's why i asked. I tried my best to stuck with STO rules by avoiding asking "how" questions. I tried to add contextuals informations, links, sources, exaplanations and then you answered with a mix of condescension and mockery. So, please, forgive me to be...a beginner asking some irrelevant questions, 
It's like if you watching a kid trying to learn to walk, asky what he's doing wrong and you answered him "Why do you use your legs like this? What are you doing with your arms? And what about your shoes? They're not walking shoes. It's so uncorrect".

Comment: Since when asking someone what they think or *to think* constitutes *condescendence and mockery*? -- You posted your first question about VB.NET in `Dec 4, 2020`, so you're not that *new* and I don't treat adults like toddlers, *that* would constitute condescendence and mockery. I've asked substantial questions that point out issues you'll have to address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot invoke a method using a delegate with a different signature. Your method is a `Function` with two `String` parameters and returns a `DataTable` while your delegate is a `Sub` with no parameters. You should declare your delegate with the same signature as the method you intend to invoke:

```vb
Public Delegate Function DoWorkDelegate(p1 As String, p2 As String) As DataTable
```

Note that the parameter names don't actually matter but you should give them appropriate names, like everything else. If the delegate will only be used to invoke one method, use the same parameter names as the method.

That said, there's really little point declaring your own delegates these days. To invoke a `Sub`, use an appropriate `Action` delegate and, to invoke a `Function`, use an appropriate `Func` delegate. Both can have up to 16 parameters.

Note that this addresses the specific question you asked but there are still issues with your code and this is definitely not the way I would go about it.